# SCALA: Generating a list of Tuple2 objects meeting some criteria

Tags: scala

I want to generate a `list` of  `Tuple2 objects`. Each tuple `(a,b)` in the list should meeting the conditions:`a` and `b` both are perfect squares,`(b/30)<a<b` 
 and `a>N` and `b>N` ( `N` can even be a `BigInt`)
  I am trying to write a `scala function` to generate `the List of Tuples` meeting the above requirements?
   This is my attempt..it works fine for Ints and Longs..But for BigInt there is sqrt problem I am facing..Here is my approach in coding as below:

```
scala>  def genTups(N:Long) ={
     |  val x = for(s<- 1L to Math.sqrt(N).toLong) yield s*s;
     |  val y = x.combinations(2).map{ case Vector(a,b) => (a,b)}.toList
     |  y.filter(t=> (t._1*30/t._2)>=1)
     | }
genTups: (N: Long)List[(Long, Long)]

scala> genTups(30)
res32: List[(Long, Long)] = List((1,4), (1,9), (1,16), (1,25), (4,9), (4,16), (4,25), (9,16), (9,25), (16,25))
```

Improved this using BigInt square-root algorithm as below:

```
def genTups(N1:BigInt,N2:BigInt) ={
    def sqt(n:BigInt):BigInt = {
        var a = BigInt(1)
        var b = (n>>5)+BigInt(8)
        while((b-a) >= 0) {
         var mid:BigInt = (a+b)>>1
         if(mid*mid-n> 0) b = mid-1
         else a = mid+1
        }; a-1 }
      val x = for(s<- sqt(N1) to sqt(N2)) yield s*s;
      val y = x.combinations(2).map{ case Vector(a,b) => (a,b)}.toList
      y.filter(t=> (t._1*30/t._2)>=1)
  }
```

I appreciate any help to improve in my algorithm .

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you have? Show your attempt and you will get advice on how to improve it, but don't just ask people to complete your assignments for you.

Comment: You don't need the condition on the `case` clause because `combinations` keeps the values in order and `a` is always `<b`. If it wasn't, the `map` would fail with an exception.

Comment: Yes..Just now I too realised that. can it improve performance a bit if I remove it?

Comment: Yes, but I just added a faster implementation you might want to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `sqrt` in you algorithm by changing the way you calculate `x` to this:

```
  val x = (BigInt(1) to N).map(x => x*x).takeWhile(_ <= N)
```

The final function is then:

```
def genTups(N: BigInt) = {
  val x = (BigInt(1) to N).map(x => x*x).takeWhile(_ <= N)
  val y = x.combinations(2).map { case Vector(a, b) if (a < b) => (a, b) }.toList
  y.filter(t => (t._1 * 30 / t._2) >= 1)
}
```

You can also re-write this as a single chain of operations like this:

```
def genTups(N: BigInt) =
  (BigInt(1) to N)
    .map(x => x * x)
    .takeWhile(_ <= N)
    .combinations(2)
    .map { case Vector(a, b) if a < b => (a, b) }
    .filter(t => (t._1 * 30 / t._2) >= 1)
    .toList
```

---

In a quest for performance, I came up with this recursive version that appears to be significantly faster

```
def genTups(N1: BigInt, N2: BigInt) = {
  def sqt(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
    var a = BigInt(1)
    var b = (n >> 5) + BigInt(8)
    while ((b - a) >= 0) {
      var mid: BigInt = (a + b) >> 1
      if (mid * mid - n > 0) {
        b = mid - 1
      } else {
        a = mid + 1
      }
    }
    a - 1
  }

  @tailrec
  def loop(a: BigInt, rem: List[BigInt], res: List[(BigInt, BigInt)]): List[(BigInt, BigInt)] =
    rem match {
      case Nil => res
      case head :: tail =>
        val a30 = a * 30
        val thisRes = rem.takeWhile(_ <= a30).map(b => (a, b))

        loop(head, tail, thisRes.reverse ::: res)
    }

  val squares = (sqt(N1) to sqt(N2)).map(s => s * s).toList

  loop(squares.head, squares.tail, Nil).reverse
}
```

Each recursion of the loop adds all the matching pairs for a given value of `a`. The result is built in reverse because adding to the front of a long list is much faster than adding to the tail.

Comment: That's small but very useful tip..Avoided exploring me for proper sqrt function for BigInt. Thanks Tim.

Comment: After examining your suggestion, I got another issue regarding performance of both approaches..In my approach I am just computing squares from 1 to sqrt(N) only, But in this approach we are computing right from 1 to N and filtering the computed squares using `takeWhile()`, where N may be very large than sqrt(N).   Do you have anything to clarify on this?

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM this could be performance killer for larger number as the combinations method would be compute intensive

Comment: You can improve things by putting `.view` before `.map` and changing `Vector` to `Seq`, but if you are going for better performance you probably need a better algorithm.

Comment: Is there any better way than using combinations method here?

Comment: significant performance improvement with @tailrec, I wrote a function for comparing performances with same test data,`
scala> comparePerforms()
NoTrec = 1281, WithTrec = 62` ( in milliseconds). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly create a function to check if number if perfect square or not.

```
def squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a: Int): Option[Int] = {
  val sqrt = math.sqrt(a)
  if (sqrt % 1 == 0)
    Some(sqrt.toInt)
  else
    None
}
```

Then, create another func that will calculate this list of tuples according to the conditions mentioned above.

```
def generateTuples(n1:Int,n2:Int)={
  for{
    b <- 1 to n2;
    a <- 1 to n1 if(b>a && squareRootOfPerfectSquare(b).isDefined && squareRootOfPerfectSquare(a).isDefined)
  } yield ( (a,b) )
}
```

Then on calling the function with parameters `generateTuples(5,10)`
 you will get an output as

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,4), (1,9), (4,9))
```

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: I think you have missed out the code for `generateTuple` and put two copies of `squareRootOfPerfectSquare` instead...

Comment: @Tim Thanks for pointing out. I am wondering why my answer was not accepted all this time. Anyways thanks !!!

Comment: Also, the question asks for a solution for `BigInt` so you can't use `sqrt` :(